# Doing a loop in mathematica with sneg package

Tags: loops, wolfram-mathematica

I got a problem getting a loop done in Mathematica while using the SNEG package (it's for calculus with fermionic operators).

Here's a little bit of my code:

```
natord = {{cjdckd, 1, 2}, {cjdckd, 1, 3}, {cjdckd, 1, 4}, {cjdck, 1, 
    1}, {cjdck, 1, 2}, {cjdck, 1, 3}, {cjdck, 1, 4},
   {cjdckd, 2, 3}, {cjdckd, 2, 4}, {cjdck, 2, 1}, {cjdck, 2, 
    2}, {cjdck, 2, 3}, {cjdck, 2, 4}, {cjdckd, 3, 4}, {cjdck, 3, 
    1}, {cjdck, 3, 2}, {cjdck, 3, 3}, {cjdck, 3, 4}, {cjdck, 4, 
    1}, {cjdck, 4, 2}, {cjdck, 4, 3}, {cjdck, 4, 4}, {cjck, 1, 
    2}, {cjck, 1, 3}, {cjck, 1, 4}, {cjck, 2, 3}, {cjck, 2, 4}, {cjck,
     3, 4}};

Do[
 
 j = natord[[ind, 2]] // ToString;
 k = natord[[ind, 3]] // ToString;
 
 cjd = c[0, j];
 cj = c[1, j];
 
 ckd = c[0, k];
 ck = c[1, k];
 
 cjck = nc[cj, ck];
 cjdck = nc[cjd, ck];
 cjdckd = nc[cjd, ckd];
 
 korr = natord[[ind, 1]];
```

After this the following code generates a list of coefficients and one single value.
The list should be appended to a List M, so I have matrix in the end and the single value is going to be in a list so I get a vector.
When I'm not doing a Do-Loop and just saying

```
j="1";
k="2";
```

and

```
korr=cjck;
```

it somehow this will do it.
As you can see in the natord list, I got 28 cases which I don't want to put in each explicitly but creating a Loop doing this for me.

Hope you can help me. If you need more code tell me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample doesn't reveal any problem you may be encountering with `Append` or `AppendTo`.

```
m = {};

Do[AppendTo[m, natord[[i]]], {i, Length[natord]}]

m == natord
```

> True